# Can I attach multiple database on SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have .mdf files that are backups of several databases, and I would like to know if it is possible to attach these files at once.

If it is also possible, for example via PHP code, I also feel free to explore.

Comment: One .mdf file = one database. You can attach multiple databases to a single SQL Server. You cannot build one database out of multiple mdf files. Typically multiple file databases use ndf for the subsequent files.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I don't want to attach multiple .mdf files to a single database. I want to attach the .mdf files and create the databases separately at once.

Comment: There are various API's to do this, all seachable online. For example in T-SQL, it's `sp_attach_db`.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I will explore

Comment: and just to clarify, SQL Server Management Studio is just the _client_ application. It connects to a SQL Server. The SQL Server is the thing you actually need to attach a MDF to. SQL Server Management Studio is the just one client you can use to do it